# How to enable $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'] in PHP?

Tags: php, apache, http

Both the local testing and live servers the PHP `$_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH']` variable isn't set. How do I enable `$_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH']` with Apache or PHP or trigger it in an HTTP request? The live server is a shared hosting account so please no *just blindly edit the httpd.conf* responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include it in a `.htaccess` file within your ROOT:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH:%{HTTP:If-None-Match}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should send an `If-None-Match` header to your endpoint. If so the `HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH` variable should contain the value of the `If-None-Match` header.

```
curl http://my/endpoint --header 'If-None-Match: "my-custom-etag-value"'
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone needs this for Nginx too, you can put this in your `nginx.conf`.

```
fastcgi_param HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH $http_if_none_match;
```